# I can't get checked row data with onRowSelected in Material UI DataGrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I'm trying to get the data of `Checked` row when it's clicked in `DataGrid` component.
When I tried to make this , I was able to get this with `onRowSelected` attribute of `DataGrid`.

But now I cannot reach this attribute. I don't now is that deprecated or else. Now, with `onSelectionModelChange` attribute, I can only get the **ıd** value of that row. But what I need is get the object of that row with fields of it. I can get what ı want with `onRowClick` attribute, but I have to get it with **checkbox selection** and ı have to make this with `DataGrid` component.

Here is my **datagrid** now

```js
<DataGrid
  rows={this.props.rows}
  columns={this.props.columns}
  pageSize={5}
  checkboxSelection
  disableSelectionOnClick
  onRowSelected={(selection) => {
    //Cannot reach any selection data. Need another attrib. attribute.
    console.log(selection);
  }}
/>
```

My columns:

```js
columnsPlants: [
  { field: 'plantId', headerName: 'ID', width: 120 },
  { field: 'name', headerName: 'Plant Name', width: 230 },
  { field: 'eic', headerName: 'EIC', width: 170 },
  { field: 'organizationETSOCode', width: 200, headerName: 'Organization ETSO' },
  {
    field: 'addPortfolio',
    headerName: 'Add to Portfolio',
    width: 200,
    editable: false,
    sortable: false,
    disableClickEventBubbling: true,
    renderCell: (params) => {
      return (
        <div
          className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
          style={{ cursor: 'pointer', marginLeft: '25px' }}
        >
          {this.AddtoPortfolio(params.row.plantId)}
        </div>
      );
    },
  },
],
```

And the data format I want to get when **checkbox selected**:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only access the row ids inside [`onSelectionModelChange`](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/#:%7E:text=onSelectionModelChange) callback (Edit [`onSelectionModelChange`] is now [`onRowSelectionModelChange`]) . If you want to get the whole row objects, use the original `rows` data and filter the others based on the selected ids.

Note: `DataGrid` stores each row ID in string internally so if the ID from your original row data is number you may want to convert it `toString()` before comparing.

```js
rows={rows}
onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
  const selectedIDs = new Set(ids);
  const selectedRowData = rows.filter((row) =>
    selectedIDs.has(row.id.toString());
  );
  console.log(selectedRowData);
}}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66424752/get-row-item-on-checkbox-selection-in-react-material-ui-data-grid]

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't working for me until I realised `onSelectionModelChange` is now `onRowSelectionModelChange` in MUI DataGrid (using "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.2.1")

For someone like me who has a hard time deciphering docs before coming to stackoverflow I had to figure this out the hard way i.e. by reading docs